# How to transfer files from semibricked android via adb

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, data, oneplus

I have a OnePlus Nord and recently updated to android 12 after a few days my phone screen became suddenly black and phone is vibrating on its own. I tried restarting it but it turns on but shows black screen and is still vibrating. I do not wish to format it as it contains many important data and I forgot to take backup while updating. But due to luck and software bug it has adb enabled and it doesn't require confirmation even though I had never enabled developer options. So I tried copying files from storage/emulated/0/ but it is empty so I switched to /data and when I type ls it shows permission denied is there a way to access it without formatting the device and safely copying all the data to pc

Comment: /data is only accessible on rooted devices. You can try to create a backup using `adb backup` but Google has deprecated this way for Android 12 apps so a lot of apps will be missing in the created backup (check using Android Backup Extractor abe).

Comment: one can't backup anything until decrypted with lock screen credentials